# Integration along a line segment

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm trying to complete the practice exam my professor posted, and got stuck on this question.

> Let C be the oriented line segment going from $\langle2,0,1\rangle$ to $\langle1,1,1\rangle$. Find $$\int_{c} z\;\mathrm dy + xy\;\mathrm dz$$

I want to use the line integral equation.  $$\int_{c} f(x,y)\;\mathrm ds=\int_{a}^{b}f(h(t)g(t))\times[r(t)]\;\mathrm dt$$

I know I need to parametrize the line segment and I did it like this:

$$(1-t)\times\langle2,0,1\rangle + t\langle1,1,1\rangle = \langle(2-t), t, 1\rangle$$

so $x= (2-t);\quad y= t;\quad z= 1;\quad 
\mathrm dx= -1,\quad\mathrm dy = 1,\quad\mathrm dz = 0;\quad r(t) = \sqrt2$

I split the problem into two sections. I want to add the two integrals at the end. Since my question doesn't use $\mathrm ds$($\mathrm dy,\mathrm dz$ instead) I figured I needed to do a change in variable(?)

$$\int_{0}^{1} z\;\mathrm dy = \int_{0}^{1}1\times\sqrt2\times\mathrm dy\times\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dy} = \int_{0}^{1}(1)\left(\sqrt2\right)(1)\;\mathrm dt = \sqrt2$$

I did the second part like this:

$$\int_{0}^{1} xy\;\mathrm dz = \int_{0}^{1} (2-t)(t)\times\sqrt2\times dz\times\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dz} = \int_{0}^{1}\left(2t-t^2\right)\times\sqrt2\times0\;\mathrm dt = 0$$

I added them to get my final answer: $\sqrt2$, but the correct answer is $1$. Can someone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you get $\int_0^1 zdy= \int_0^1 \sqrt{2} dy$.   At both endpoints, (2, 0, 1) to (1, 1, 1), z= 1 so z= 1 along the entire line and the integral, with respect to y, is just $\int_0^1 1 dy= 1$.  Was it because the length of the line from (2, 0, 1) to (1, 1, 1) has length $\sqrt{(2-1)^2+ (0-1)^2+ (1- 1)^2}= \sqrt{2}$?  That would be relevant if you were integrating with respect to arclength but you are not- you are integrating only parallel to the y-axis.

Comment: Oh!! it makes sense! Thank you!